# Endless runner game level generation on the fly in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I have an Endless Runner game and for scrolling I use two moderately (around 1500 pixels) nodes for scrolling.

They follow each other, like so `|firstNode||secondNode|`
Each of them has many objects on them, trees, various objects with physics bodies.
When one of them leaves screen I remove all objects from it, reattach it to the end of the node that is actually on screen and recreate all objects again - in one of the random presets.

But there is a problem, when I recreate the objects for the node, I experience small lag, for like 0.1 second, and this makes my physics off and player often dies.

How do I make so that the game does not lag during regeneration of the objects?

I tried using GCD to recreate the thing in another thread, but this fails since I use joint and pin connections and it requires to be in main thread to do this.

I also thought about pre caching those preset parts somewhere, but since I connect the joints to actual physics world this does not seem possible. I also need to recreate coins that player may have picked.

How do I go about this? How do I remove lag when recreating large amount of objects in realtime?

Comment: You should not create ALL the objects for your new node but rather only create those objects which are about to come into the view. This will increase your FPS, save you memory and lag time.

Comment: @sangony I create the objects that will come into view, they will come in couple of seconds.

Comment: did you test on a real device?  Simulators tend to lag more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement pooling of your objects.

Create all your objects upfront, and then manage reusing them as needed. When you need an object, grab it from the pool. When done with it, return it to the pool

rinse, repeat.

In terms of pool sizes, base that on how many of a given object will ever be needed at once.

Comment: This helped, I made few arrays of objects that I create on startup and instead position them on new thing. I still have to create physics bodies, but lag is gone.

Comment: Good to hear. Yep, object creation can be the cause of lag if you are constantly creating and killing objects. Also, you reduce need for garbage collection. The virtual landfill is not getting filled with dead trees either.